# Changing a Table View Controller to a View Controller

Tags: ios

I have a Table View Controller that displays information using JSON. I want to change the styling of my app, and I don't want it to have that "table" view that it has now. Whats the easiest way to change my Table View Controller to a regular View Controller, the biggest problem I have is that the code uses a tableView and I dont know how to get it to work as a regular view controller.

I using a Storyboard with a TableViewController thats linked to a controller called UpcomingReleasesViewController.

I want my app:
[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ehs2vpsv3671s2j/Photo%20Sep%2003%2C%203%2015%2042%20PM.png]

To look like this:
[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q5yfhrs4fr8uvvm/Photo%20Aug%2029%2C%201%2011%2035%20AM.png]

Comment: copy and paste the .h file of the viewController. And answer Rob's question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My original answer was assuming you just wanted to convert from a `UITableViewController` to a `UIViewController`. Looking at your screen snapshots, I infer you really want to switch from a `UITableViewController` to a `UICollectionViewController` (which is an iOS 6 feature than allows you to do precisely what you want).

In that case, change your base class to `UICollectionViewController`, and replace your [`UITableViewDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods with [`UICollectionViewDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDataSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods. And then redesign your scene using a Collection View Controller.

See the [Collection View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more information. Or see WWDC 2012 sessions [Introducing Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=205) or [Advanced Collection Views and Building Custom Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=219).

If you need to support iOS versions prior to 6, then you have to do this collection view style coding yourself manually, putting your image views on a scroll view and using a standard `UIViewController`. It require more effort than using a collection view, but can be done.

---

Original answer:

If this view controller will have a table view on it, but you just want to add more controls to the scene? If so, just change the view controller's base class from `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController`, create the new scene, add a table view to it, and specify the table view's delegate and data source to be the view controller:

[image]

Also, make sure you define an `IBOutlet` for your table view (and if you call it `tableView`, that will minimize any coding changes needed).

[image]

If you do that, you can quickly convert a `UITableViewController` based controller to a `UIViewController` with minimal code changes.

Comment: I want my app:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ehs2vpsv3671s2j/Photo%20Sep%2003%2C%203%2015%2042%20PM.png

To look like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/q5yfhrs4fr8uvvm/Photo%20Aug%2029%2C%201%2011%2035%20AM.png

Comment: @ChrisBedoya See my revised answer with links for resources re collection views.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to make something like your new UI mockup, look into [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html). You'll see many of the same concepts (i.e. dataSource, delegate method signatures are similar) that are used in UITableViews used in the collectionView API.